# Executing bash command and getting the output in C

Tags: c, linux, bash, command

Hello I have seen some solutions on the internet, all of them are basically creating a file, however I want to store them in an array of char. Speed is really important for me and I don't want to spend any time for working on hard drive. So `popen()` is not a real solution for me.

Comment: `popen` doesn't open a file.  It runs a program and connects the output directly to a C input stream.  I know the stream's type is called `FILE*` but it's not really a file.

Comment: What is your objection to `popen` ? That would be the normal way to do this.

Comment: check here:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/executing-shell-command-in-cc-and.html

Comment: If speed is your main concern, why are you trying to execute a bash command in the first place?

Comment: Also, please consider reading `man 3 popen` it contains everything you need to know, including why `popen` is the way to go here.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a working code snippet:

```
char bash_cmd[256] = "ls -l";
char buffer[1000];
FILE *pipe;
int len; 

pipe = popen(bash_cmd, "r");

if (NULL == pipe) {
    perror("pipe");
    exit(1);
} 

fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), pipe);

len = strlen(buffer);
buffer[len-1] = '\0'; 

pclose(pipe);
```

Comment: It's not a working snippet, you must modify the `buffer` variable not `bash_cmd` after `fgets`

Answer (score 2):

If you would read the manpage of popen, you would notice the following:

> The popen() function opens a process by creating a pipe,  forking, 
>   and invoking  the shell. [...] The  return  value  from popen() is a
>   normal standard I/O stream in all respects save  that  it  must  be 
>   closed  with  pclose()  rather  than fclose(3). [...] **reading from a
>   "popened"  stream  reads  the  command's standard output**, and the
>   command's standard input is the same as that of the process that
>   called popen().

(emphasis mine)

As you can see, a call to `popen` results in the `stdout` of the command being piped into your program through an **I/O stream**, which has nothing to do with disk I/O at all, but rather with interprocess communication managed by the operating system.

(As a sidenote: It's generally a good idea to rely on the basic functionality of the operating system, within reason, to solve common problems. And since `popen` is part of `POSIX.1-2001` you can rely on it to be available on all standards compliant operarting systems, even windows)

EDIT: if you want to know more, read this: http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen

Answer (score 2):

Never forget Knuth's saying that "premature optimization is the root of all evil". Don't worry about performance until it matters, and then *measure* before doing anything. Except for very rare situations, the value of your time is much higher than the cost of the program runs.

Jon Bentley's "Writing efficient programs" (sadly out of print, in his ["Programming Pearls"](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/) one chapter is a summary) is a detailed discussion on how to make programs run faster (if it is worthwhile); and only as the very last measure, to squeeze out the last possible 2% of performance (after cutting run time down by half) it recommends using changes like you propose. The cited book includes some very entertaining war stories of "performance optimizations" that were a complete waste (optimize code that isn't ever used, oprimize the code run while the operating system twiddles its thumbs, ...).

Answer (score 0):

If speed is important to you, you can write your own version of popen.

It may make sense, since popen()
- creates a pipe
- forks
- executes the shell (very expensive!)
- the shell than creates a pipe, forks, executes your program

Your customized version could reduce the procedure to:
- creates a pipe
- forks
- executes your program

You could even extend popen to control the commands STDOUT, STDERR and STDIN seperately.
I wrote such a routine, see https://github.com/rockdaboot/mget/blob/master/libmget/pipe.c
It is GPL'ed.

You call mget_popen3() with FILE pointers or mget_fd_popen3() with file descriptors.
At least, it should give you an idea on how to do it.

Answer (score -2):

Do you mind having more than one C programs?If you don't ,you can make use of the command line arguments. In the fist C program you can do the following

```
system("YourCommand | SecondProgram");
```

The `SecondProgram` will be the "executable" of the second C program you will be writing. In the second C program you can receive the output of the command `YourCommand` as a command line argument in the `SecondProgram`. For that purpose you may begin the main() of second C program as below

```
main(int argc,char *argv[])
```

The array `argv` will have the output of the `YourCommand` and `argc` will contain the number of elements in the array `argv`.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin State the reason

Comment: I don't really think this is a fast way for me to do.
Besides I do not understand how would the second program send the output back to the first program...

Comment: The maybe most important reason is that you can't be sure that SecondProgram is really the Program you want it to be. EDIT: for more information see http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/11153/

Comment: @SarpKaya Implement the  output processing in the second program. Is that a problem in your context? By the by which command are you trying to execute? Can't a system call be a solution?