# How do I get shell output from system()?

Tags: c++, unix

I'm calling system() to trigger a command. I can see the output of the command in the Xcode console – but I don't know how to capture it in a string.

I tried setting a string to the system() call itself, but the string was set to 0.

This is the code I wrote:

```
string node = "/usr/local/bin/node ~/Desktop/chromix-master/script/chromix.js ";
string commandStr = node + "url";
char command[1024];
strcpy(command,commandStr.c_str());
system(command);
```

Specifically, I'm trying to get the URL of the currently focused tab in chrome using [smblott's Chromix utility](https://github.com/smblott-github/chromix).

Comment: you can get this from following links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393762/executing-bash-command-and-getting-the-output-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `system()`, use `popen()` to open a pipe from which you can read the program output.

```
FILE *p = popen(command, "r");
// ... use p as a file
pclose(p);
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Do you think you can point me in the right direction for reading the file into a string?